# remove all the values from the column and make it blank

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, replace

I have a dataframe :

```
a b
1 dasd
2 fsfr12341
3 %%$dasd11
4 &^hkyo1
```

I need to remove all the values in column b and make it a blank column

```
a b
1
2
3
4
```

Kindly help me on this.
thanks alot

Comment: blank as in empty strings or null?

Comment: Try `df['b']=''`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing the `b` column to empty strings `''`, like this:

```
df['b'] = ''
```